Export data from dynamic XML hierarchy in SQL Server
I want to get the lowest value in the hierarchy in a dynamic XML file.
I try to write a dynamic expression for reading from XML file:
patdata.value('(*[local-name() = sql:column("DataMng.Root")]/*[local-name() = sql:column("textMng.FieldId")]/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')

DataMng.Root= 'rc0036'
FieldId='s4356/L4356/F4357'
but I am getting **NULL **although there is value on this XML file.
When I write the following expression, I get the output I want:
patdata.value('(*[local-name() = sql:column("DataMng.Root")]/s4356/L4356/F4357/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')

there is the XML file:
<rc0036>
 <F2739>9893</F2739>
 <F2740>12</F2740>
 <F2741>ד"ר נאג'ד יאסין</F2741>
 <F0242>16/04/2024</F0242>
 <F5453>16/04/2024</F5453>
 <F4301>16/04/2024</F4301>
 <F5454>מרינה</F5454>
 <F1209>מרינה</F1209>
 <F1903>מעקב זקיקים</F1903>
 <F0984>מרינה</F0984>
 <F0308>01/04/2024</F0308>
 <F0415>וגינלי</F0415>
 <F2966>טיפול</F2966>
 <s4356>
  <L4356 line="1">
   <F0418>16/04/2024</F0418>
   <F0462>16</F0462>
   <F0071>100</F0071>
   <F0987>בינוני</F0987>
   <F4357>5</F4357>
   <F4357>6</F4357>
   <F1617>מרינה</F1617>
   <F1013/>
  </L4356>
 </s4356>
</rc0036>


I added a pic of part of the xml file

Did you know that the local-name() XPath function refers to a single node, not a hierarchy? i.e.: If you feed it a node-set it only works on the first node.

Please don't use images... Add the xml to the question as text.

I added the xml as a text

Since SQL Server won't allow you to specify dynamic XPaths to the query(), nodes() and value() XML methods, even with sql:column() and sql:variable() tricks, have you considered turning the problem around? i.e.: use a CTE to shred the XML generating XPaths for each node then match the generated XPaths against your expression to return that node's value.

While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements.
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question as text, no images.

A minimal reproducible example is not provided. So, I am shooting from the hip.
Here is a couple of ways of doing it.
First method is a hack.
The 2nd method is much more reliable. It is using XQuery FLWOR expression.
SQL
DECLARE @xml XML = 
N'<rc0036>
 <F2739>9893</F2739>
 <F2740>12</F2740>
 <F0242>16/04/2024</F0242>
 <F5453>16/04/2024</F5453>
 <F4301>16/04/2024</F4301>
 <F5454>מרינה</F5454>
 <F1209>מרינה</F1209>
 <F1903>מעקב זקיקים</F1903>
 <F0984>מרינה</F0984>
 <F0308>01/04/2024</F0308>
 <F0415>וגינלי</F0415>
 <F2966>טיפול</F2966>
 <s4356>
  <L4356 line="1">
   <F0418>16/04/2024</F0418>
   <F0462>16</F0462>
   <F0071>100</F0071>
   <F0987>בינוני</F0987>
   <F4357>5</F4357>
   <F4357>6</F4357>
   <F1617>מרינה</F1617>
   <F1013/>
  </L4356>
 </s4356>
</rc0036>';

SELECT @xml.value('min(//*)', 'INT') AS result;

SELECT @xml.query('
    for $x in min(//*[xs:int(text()[1]) instance of xs:int])
    return $x
').value('.', 'INT') AS result;

SELECT REPLACE(@xml.query('data(/rc0036/s4356/L4356/F4357/text())')
    .value('.', 'VARCHAR(20)'), SPACE(1),',') AS result;

Output #1



result




5



Output #2



result




5,6




Amazing!! thank you!  now how can I export all the data under this tag in one row? I mean the output will be 5,6 (under tag s4356/L4356/F4357)

I updated the answer. Check it out.
